# How to use cmake on the machine which cmake is not installed

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I am using the cmake to build my project. However, I need to build this project on a machine that I do not have the permission to install any software on it. I thought I can use the generated makefile but it has the dependencies on CMake,and says cmake:command not found.Is there any solution that force the generated makefile do not have any cmake related command such as check the system version? Thanks

Comment: I risk sounding gullible, but can't you just edit the makefile by hand?

Comment: @StoryTeller, in fact no, not very usefully.  cmake-generated Makefiles generally have a great number and wide variety of `cmake` dependencies.  And anyway, to the extent that a makefile such as you could obtain by hand-editing a cmake-generated makefile would be portable to other systems, you don't need cmake in the first place.

Comment: Although you cannot install software to system locations, you may nevertheless be able to install a *private* copy of `cmake`.  Presumably you have local storage to which you can write, otherwise you have a more fundamental obstacle to overcome than lack of `cmake`.

Comment: But before even going there, it is worth considering whether you might persuade the sysadmin to install `cmake` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any solution that force the generated makefile do not have any cmake related command such as check the system version?

No.  There is no incentive for `cmake` to provide such an option, because the whole point of the `cmake` system is that the `cmake` program examines the build machine and uses what it finds to generate a Makefile (if you're using that generator) appropriate to the machine.  The generated Makefiles are tailored to the machine, and it is not assumed that they would be suitable for any other machine, so there is no reason to suppose that one would need to use one on a machine that does not have `cmake`.  In fact, if you look at the generated Makefiles you'll find all sorts of dependencies on `cmake`.

Depending on the breadth of your target machine types, you might consider the Autotools instead.  Some people dislike them, and they're not a good choice if you want to support Microsoft's toolchain on Windows, but they do have the advantage that an Autotools-based build system can be used to build software on machines that do not themselves have the Autotools installed.

Answer (score 0):

one easy solution is to use static libraries and the 'static' parameter in the command line.

Then you should be able to drop the executable on the target machine and run it.

Comment: In other words, your suggestion is to build elsewhere, on a machine that does have `cmake`, in a way that yields an executable usable on the target machine?  If the point is to *have* the software on the target machine, as opposed to specifically *building* the software on that machine (which is what the question actually asks) then this is an option well worth considering.